# Filter grep results down to paths to existing files only

Tags: bash, unix, grep, sh, zsh

I'm using `git diff` and `grep` to give me list of all files from a specific folder that were changed in the last commit:

```sh
paths=$(git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1 | grep "desired_folder/")
```

Now I need to filter the list only to strings that actually point to an existing file, and get rid of strings that don't. How can I do this?

The `--diff-filter` flag is not useful for me, because I need to get the change list on one branch and then filter only to files that exist on a different branch.

**Edit - example behaviour:**
Input string:

```
"file1.txt file2.txt folder/file3.txt"
```

Current folder tree:

```
|-- file1.txt
|-- folder/
    |-- file3.txt
```

Expected output:

```
# file2.txt got removed, because it does not represent 
# path to an existing file
"file1.txt folder/file3.txt"
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data with expected output. Don't post them as images or comments but edit them to your original post. Thanks.

Comment: Why is this tagged bash and zsh and sh? Pick one shell to use.

Comment: @JamesBrown : I made an edit, does this work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop though the results from `git diff` with with a while loop, the syntax is a bit weird, to avoid having to create a subshell:

```
while read; do
  :
done < <(cmd)
```

In your case:

```
while IFS= read file
do
  [ -f "$file" ] || continue # skip non existing files
  echo "$file" # file exists and is a regular file
done < <(git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1)
```

You can stick your grep behind the git diff, just note you'll need to keep in inside the process substitution:

```
< <(git diff ... | grep ...)
```

The while loop will read each line from the output of `git`/`grep` and store the line in the variable `file`.

Note that `git diff --name-only` show files relative to the root of the git repo, you might want to add `--relative` to make them relative to the current working directory.

Answer (score -1):

If you've ended up with a space( ) delimiter string, we can loop over those filenames, and check if they exist.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
res=""
files="file1.txt file2.txt folder/file3.txt"
for path in ${files// / }; do
    if [ -f $path ]; then
        [ -z $res ] && res="$path" || res="${res} ${path}"
    fi
done
echo "$res"
```

```
file1.txt folder/file3.txt
```

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY6xDsIwDER3f8WRVmwQAWPFxGegDi1xSAQ0KE0lROm3lyTqwICXxHf3bLdNb@a5WMnWdrKNDVGBk@cmMBS3wxXa3rmnx01ZD@3uij0FN1xMNnbb8AqLLJNwSAIVRJ77oxCU6aP4ycbf/i8Vw87j2QQD26EcMyolJKYKyhFiWY0zNhpljtUVguEuO6mi9UYZN6PGeo18Qk4KfD5LO8ZnitOTPImMakvKdUx8MQ4i8WKevw)

**Warning**: Since the paths are separated by a space, the path itself should **not** contain a space.